# What are all the "The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old" warnings from event-exporter container?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are getting a lot of warnings in our GCP kubernetes cluster event logs from the event-exporter container.

```
event-exporter  Jun 4, 2018, 10:45:15 AM    W0604 14:45:15.416504 1 reflector.go:323] github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/event-exporter/watchers/watcher.go:55: watch of *v1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
event-exporter  Jun 4, 2018, 10:37:04 AM    W0604 14:37:04.331239 1 reflector.go:323] github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/event-exporter/watchers/watcher.go:55: watch of *v1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
event-exporter  Jun 4, 2018, 10:28:37 AM    W0604 14:28:37.249901 1 reflector.go:323] github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/event-exporter/watchers/watcher.go:55: watch of *v1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
event-exporter  Jun 4, 2018, 10:21:38 AM    W0604 14:21:38.141687 1 reflector.go:323] github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/event-exporter/watchers/watcher.go:55: watch of *v1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
event-exporter  Jun 4, 2018, 10:15:38 AM    W0604 14:15:38.087389 1 reflector.go:323] github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/event-exporter/watchers/watcher.go:55: watch of *v1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
event-exporter  Jun 4, 2018, 10:04:35 AM    W0604 14:04:35.981083 1 reflector.go:323] github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/event-exporter/watchers/watcher.go:55: watch of *v1.Event ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
```

Anyone know why these warnings are appearing and how can I fix them?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Including the full error message?

Comment: I got them too, did you fixed them already @Miguel Clark?

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/52925973/9065705

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes resource versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910322/kubernetes-resource-versioning)

Answer (score 1):

This means that there are newer version(s) of the watched resource after the time the client api last acquired a list within that watch window.

The client needs to re-list to acquire the newest version. This is a somewhat common occurrence when using the client api as logging is buried deep within.