# Kubernetes resource versioning

Tags: version-control, kubernetes

Using `kubectl get with -o yaml` on a resouce , I see that every resource is versioned:

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-16T21:44:10Z
  name: my-config
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "163"
```

I wonder what is the significance of these versioning and for what purpose these are used? ( use cases )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more detailed explanation, that helped me to understand exactly how this works:

> All the objects you’ve created throughout this book—Pods,
>   `ReplicationControllers, Services, Secrets` and so on—need to be
>   stored somewhere in a persistent manner so their manifests survive API
>   server restarts and failures. For this, Kubernetes uses `etcd`, which
>   is a fast, distributed, and consistent key-value store.  The only
>   component that talks to `etcd` directly is the Kubernetes API server.
>   All other components read and write data to etcd indirectly through
>   the API server.
>
> This brings a few benefits, among them a more robust *optimistic
>   locking* system as well as validation; and, by abstracting away the
>   actual storage mechanism from all the other components, it’s much
>   simpler to replace it in the future. It’s worth emphasizing that etcd
>   is the only place Kubernetes stores cluster state and metadata.
>
> *Optimistic concurrency control* (sometimes referred to as *optimistic
>   locking*) is a method where instead of locking a piece of data and
>   preventing it from being read or updated while the lock is in place,
>   the piece of data includes a version number. Every time the data is
>   updated, the version number increases. When updating the data, the
>   version number is checked to see if it has increased between the time
>   the client read the data and the time it submits the update. If this
>   happens, the update is rejected and the client must re-read the new
>   data and try to update it again. The result is that when two clients
>   try to update the same data entry, only the first one succeeds.
>
> The result is that when two clients try to update the same data entry,
>   only the first one succeeds

Marko Luksa, "Kubernetes in Action"

So, all the Kubernetes resources include a `metadata.resourceVersion` field, which clients need to pass back to the API server when updating an object. If the version doesn’t match the one stored in `etcd`, the API server rejects the update

Answer (score 3):

The main purpose for the resourceVersion on individual resources is optimistic locking. You can fetch a resource, make a change, and submit it as an update, and the server will reject the update with a conflict error if another client has updated it in the meantime (their update would have bumped the resourceVersion, and the value you submit tells the server what version you think you are updating)

Comment: So in case of conflict , it will be resolved on the client side? I mean the client will need to get the new version first?

Comment: and how the server knows the version that the client have? if the version field is removed from client side , or it is managed internally by some other mechanism , im not sure how this version tracking works

Comment: Yes, in case of conflict, client needs to: re-GET the resource, do again the changes it wants to make (but keep the new `metadata.resourceVersion` returned by the server), send new update (PUT) attempt.  See https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#concurrency-control-and-consistency and a recommended implementation https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/util/retry#RetryOnConflict.  Conceptually similar to "git fetch; git rebase; git push --ff-only", this flow allows _arbitrary_ client-side "conflict resolution".

Comment: For simple "set these few fields" use cases, consider instead using PATCH —resolved on server without conflict risk.  
For something akin to 3-way "git merge", see also `kubectl apply`, and the somewhat different "server-side apply" (these two use extra metadata, not just resourceVersion.  and they're for specific scenarios, not everything needs them...)